# Only allow browser to safe list

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Using Google Chrome, does an extention exist which only allows me to browse to sites which I have personally added to a safe list.  Any link which is not in the safe list will be automatically blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) for this by adding a filter that matches everything and then adding your whitelisted sites as *exception rules* as described in the [Adblock Plus documentation](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

Comment: +1. A whitelist is the only way to achieve this, and this is a good idea using existing blocking tools.